# Command libtool failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, xcode4.1

I've created a static library C++ project but when I compile I get the following error:

[image: XCode Error Message]

XCode 4.1 (Lion) doesn't show me any more information what's going wrong. I'm using clang.

How can I find out what went wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have read elsewhere, and confirmed myself, that the problem is that Xcode is suppressing the output from stdout.

As a work around, in Xcode, flip open the display of the commands being executed and copy and paste them into a Terminal session and run lib tool from there.

Comment: This was a perfect suggestion. I have was having problems with libtool failing and it was a simple problem with the PATH - but there were no error messages. The only additional thing I had to do was replace the setenv statements in the log with export ones because I'm using the bash shell.  Thanks.